# How to replace scenes with some action with the help of CCDirector?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to replace one scene with another with fade out - fade in effect.(old scene fades out(to the black screen),and then new scene fades in).

i found solution manually to decrease opacity of one scene and then launch

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorld scene]];
```

But i suppose there is another solution with the use of actions. 
Please, help me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in this tutorial http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2143!

You’ll find all the transitions listed in the Transitions.h file in the cocos2d folder.

```
 [[Director sharedDirector] replaceScene:[RotoZoomTransition transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[PlayScene node]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on this, but there is a class named CCTransitionScene and it's subclasses (e g CCFadeTransition) might do what you want.